# ERROR: got error when setting up GCP MySQL server

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

Here is my steps that can replicate:

Compute Engine Creation:

```
1.select F1-Micro instance.
2.Select Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Minimal.
```

Install:

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

My question is how can I get no error when setting up MySQL server in GCP?

Here is the error:

````
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start-pre) since Fri 2021-01-29 20:58:52 UTC; 3s ago
Cntrl PID: 2338 (mysql-systemd-s)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 682)
     Memory: 1.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             ├─2338 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
             ├─2356 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
             ├─2357 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
             ├─2358 [my_print_defaul]
             ├─2359 sed -n s/^--datadir=//p
             └─2360 tail -n 1
Jan 29 20:58:49 instance-1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Killing process 2233 (mysqld) with signal SIGKILL.
Jan 29 20:58:51 instance-1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jan 29 20:58:51 instance-1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 29 20:58:51 instance-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jan 29 20:58:52 instance-1 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jan 29 20:58:52 instance-1 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 29 20:58:52 instance-1 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.46-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processin
g triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server```
````

Comment: The post install script is failing. First thing I would do, is select a larger instance size.  The minimum requirements for MySQL 8.0 are 2 GB RAM and 2 CPU cores. An F1-micro instance is too small. I recommend something like e2-medium as a realistic minimum.

Comment: I'm able to run MySQL 8.0 on 2 GB RAM and 1 CPU cores but as per the [mysql-doc](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html) minimum hardware requirements is 1 CPU and 4GB of RAM

Comment: @Mahboob - Thank you.

Comment: @lin_s use this gcloud command to set the memory for the instance "gcloud compute instances set-machine-type mysql  --zone us-central1-a --custom-cpu=1 --custom-memory=2GB" please stop the instance to change the machine type.